# Logical OR and ternary operator evaluation order

Tags: c#, operator-precedence

> Here, operators with the highest precedence appear at the top of the table, those with the lowest appear at the bottom. Within an expression, higher precedence operators are evaluated first.
>
> Logical OR ||  Left to right
>
> Conditional    ?:  Right to left

Example:

```
if ( true || false ? false : true )
{
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("WHY?"));
}
```

How I see it should be:
`true || (false ? false : true)`

How I think it work in my case:
`(true || false) ? false : true`

Why the condition will never be fulfilled if the ***conditional OR*** has a higher priority over the ***ternary*** operator?

UPD1:
[Look, the first and third condition are marked unreachable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGZnc.png)

UPD2:
The logical OR should not even check the conditions following it, if it has already found one true

Comment: It will always be true because ```||``` is short-circuit. If the first operand evaluates to ```true```, the rest will be ignored.

Comment: @Shawn The question is specifically *what* is the first statement, `true` or `true || false`.

Comment: Check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) regarding operator precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator precedence is all about solving ambiguities. Let's say for example we have two operators `op1` and `op2` and the following expression:

```
x = a op1 b op2 c
```

We could resolve this logically as

```
tmp = a op1 b
x = tmp op2 c
```

But it would also be possible to evaluate `op2` first, like so:

```
tmp = b op2 c
x = a op1 tmp
```

This is ambigous. To solve the ambiguity we could either demand parentheses or have to give one of the operators higher precedence. This is basically the same what we use in mathematics with an expression like `1 + 2 * 3` where the multiplication has higher precedence and has to be calculated first.

Wat does that mean for your example? As you've already written, `||` has a higher precedence than `?:`. This means that

```
true || false
```

will be evaluated first and always results in `true`. So your ternary effectively becomes

```
true ? false : true
```

and will always result in `false`.

How does the compiler reach that decision? Let's have a (simplified) look at the steps:

1. initially the compiler sees `true` which is already a value.
2. the compiler sees `||` an knows now that there has to follow another value or evaluated expression.
3. the compiler then sees `false`. This would be a value but since it could be part of another expression it's not done yet.
4. next, the compiler encounters `?` which it identifies this as the ternary operator
5. since the ternary has a lower precedence than `||` it has to treat the entire expression `true || false` as the first operand of the ternary.

As to why the ternary operator has a lower precedence than `||` I can only speculate that it is for consistency. The ternary is not only the only operator with three operands but also only the second and the third need to have the same datatype whereas the first is always a `bool`. The lower precedence ensures that these two assignments are semantically the same:

```
bool b = condition1 || condition2 ? true : false;
int i = condition1 || condition2 ? 23 : 42;
```

Comment: What confuses the OP is why the `||` operator, evaluating first, claims the adjacent `true || false` as its two arguments out of the entire expression, as opposed to `true || (false ? ..)`.

Comment: @GSerg where do you think I'm failing to explain just that?

Comment: You are just handwaving it by saying `true || false` will be evaluated first (as opposed to seemingly logical `true || (false ? false : true)`).

Comment: @GSerg I'm not handwaving. I explicitely state that this is the _consequence_ of `||` having a higher precedence.

Comment: Yes, this is what *will* happen, but it's easy to think, like the OP did, that the higher precedence of the `||` operator means that it splits the entire expression into two parts to the left and to the right of itself, and uses these two parts as its two arguments. While in fact it only claims the most adjacent expression term, which is due to the grammar rather than to the operator precedence.

Comment: @BillTür that is, the left side is considered as a general expression, despite the priority of operations?

Comment: @ВиталийКамалин I've added more explanation to my answer. I hope I could make it clearer for you.